# Dispaly a RGB image with vtk python

Tags: python, rgb, vtk

I want to Display a RGB image with the vtk module python. The image was saved in .vti format. I wrote the following simple code but it shows the image in gray-scale color. How i can show that in RGB color?

**Image for reference :**

[image]

```
import vtk
import nrrd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = plt.imread('RGB.tif')

header = {}
header['encoding'] = 'raw'

nrrd.write('Vug.vti', im ,header)

file_name = 'Vug.vti'

# Read the source file.
reader = vtk.vtkNrrdReader()
reader.SetFileName(file_name)
reader.Update()  

# Map the image through the lookup table
color = vtk.vtkImageMapToColors()
#color.SetLookupTable(table)
color.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

# Display the image
actor = vtk.vtkImageActor()
actor.GetMapper().SetInputConnection(color.GetOutputPort())

renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(actor)

window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
window.AddRenderer(renderer)

# Set up the interaction
interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
window.SetInteractor(interactor)
window.Render()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug. Can you share a source file ? By the way, you didn't write in a `.vti` file format. You write nrrd file format and set .vti as extension.

Comment: I shared the image. This code shows this image in gray-scale. How can I display that in RGB?

Comment: In your script you load a tif file to write it as nrrd with vti extension and then you share a png ... So what is your original file ?? VTK supports reader for each of those file format, they should render RGB by default. You can try without the vtkImageMapToColors filter

Comment: That is my original image but in .tif format but this is not important. Assume a RGB image in any format. How can I show that with vtk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following with vtk9

```
import vtk

# Read the source file.
reader = vtk.vtkPNGReader()
reader.SetFileName("oIu8j.png")
reader.Update()

# Display the image
actor = vtk.vtkImageActor()
actor.GetMapper().SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(actor)

window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
window.AddRenderer(renderer)

# Set up the interaction
interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetRenderWindow(window)
interactor.Initialize()
interactor.Start()
```